# Splash Screen does not change the orientation in iPad?

Tags: ipad, splash-screen, orientation-changes

Am working in iPad app. I have 4 images for Splash screen (Landscape Right,Left and Portrait,PortraitUpsideDown). When i launch the app in Portrait mode the Splash screen appears good, but it i change the orientation to Landscaper the Splash screen does not changes their orientation. Can you please suggest me any ideas? Today i need to submit the app. Please help me. Thanks in advance. Here is my code,

```
 -(void) showSplash
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)  //  UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
    {       
        NSLog(@"Splash Landscape");
        UIViewController *splash=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
        splachview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        splachview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape.png"];
        [splash.view addSubview:splachview];

        splachview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        splachview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:splash animated:NO];
        [self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
        [splash release];
        [splachview release];
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
             orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) //  UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
    {
        NSLog(@"Splash Portrait");
        UIViewController *splash=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
        splachview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
        splachview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait.png"];
        [splash.view addSubview:splachview];

        splachview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        splachview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:splash animated:NO];
        [self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
        [splash release];
        [splachview release];
    }   
}
```

Please correct my mistake. The splash screen does not change its orientation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your splash files as

`Default-Landscape.png` and `Default-Landscape.png` for iPad
`Default.png' and`Default@2x.png` for iPhone.

Remember file names are case sensitive so double check them

Comment: Thanks Mr.Saurabh. I have named these to splash screens Default-LandscapeLeft.png, Default-LandscapeLeft.png, Default-Portrait.png, Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png. Is this correct or whether i need to change the name above you mentioned. Please help me. Today i need to submit the app. Thanks.

Comment: One more clarification. I have two images for landscape right and left. There i need to change the name. Please help me.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the name but, when i rotate(Change the orientation) the ipad the splash screen not supporting to orientations. Can you please help me. I will post my code. Please correct my mistake. Thanks.